# Getting Error: first error: CANNOT_MODIFY_MANAGED_OBJECT, Cannot modify managed object: entity=ObjectPermissions, component=null, state=UNMANAGED: []

Tags: apex, managed-package, permission-sets, postinstall

I am getting the below error while installing the managed package, and the post installation script is running.

```
First error: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: CANNOT_MODIFY_MANAGED_OBJECT, Cannot modify managed object: entity=ObjectPermissions, component=null, state=UNMANAGED: []
```

The whole scenario is as below:

I have given standard object permissions in permission set, and permission set is part of my manage package. But as per the Salesforce limitation, we cannot package standard object permission in the permission set. Permissions will not reflect on the installed org, which is so annoying. Here is the link to the ideaexchange for the same:

https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000GdxqTUAR/permission-sets-allow-standard-object-permissions-to-be-packaged

So as a workaround, I need to assign permissions to the permission set in the post installation script via Apex. Here is the example code link for it:

https://github.com/kollklienstuber/PermSetAutomationExample

I have done the same as the code referred in the above link, but it is giving an issue as mentioned above.

I am installing the package with the System Administrator user, which I think has all the required access. Still, if someone knows of any access that I need to check, please provide that. Does anyone have any ideas or workarounds for this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot modify the Permission Set included in the managed package.
As a solution, you can create a new Permission Set (out of the package) in the post-installation script.
The post-install script before insert should check for the presence of Permission Sets with a duplicate Label or Name in the database. This is important for further updates of the package with new versions.

Comment: Thanks, Yoko. But I am checking that as well.

Answer (score 0):

I have found out why it was giving an error.

Initially, while writing the post installation script, I was inserting records of my custom objects and also doing DML on PermissionSet, ObjectPermission and fieldPermission. So in compiling, it gave me below error:

```
System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: MIXED_DML_OPERATION, DML
operation on setup object is not permitted after you have updated a non-setup object (or vice versa)
```

So to separate the transaction in a standard way, I have created a future method, and in that, I wrote logic for the creation of Permissionset, ObjectPermission and FieldPermission.

Somehow, due to the future method, it was giving me issues. As I was trying different things on this, I moved this logic out from the future method. And voila, it worked. I am not sure what is wrong with the future. I will try to find the root cause for it but as a solution i have to move logic from future and had to settle with other logic for non setup object record creation.

If someone do have more insight on this please let me know. Thanks in advance !!